# GUI doesn't work, flashing underscore on boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, gui

Ubuntu version is 12.04.3. My computer is a Asus laptop, UL30Jt with a Nvidia graphics card. I previously had problems getting the graphics drivers to work, but I resolved that previously today. Afterwards I attempted to reboot and it worked fine, then I installed glfw and afterwards it won't start the gui after restarting.

I am not completely sure, but I think it was after I installed glfw, and it's dependencies xorg-dev and libglu1-mesa-dev.

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> brings up the terminal where I can login.

I tried running for example glxinfo, which just prints:

> Error: unable to open display.

I tried running glxinfo previously, when I was trying to figure out my driver problems nad it printed .. information of some kind. (Different from this error message, I dont remember what it was.)

I have been using Ubuntu for about 4 months, so I am not terribly experienced with different useful commands.

I have looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078) without finding anything useful.

startx gets a fatal error:

> Fatal server error: no screens found

`sudo service lightdm start` or `sudo start lightdm` just takes me back to the blinking underscore, and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> takes me  back to the terminal.

I tried running `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` (which installed a bunch of stuff) and then rebooting which had no effect.

This also happened the last time I tried to install glfw, I don't know if it is the actual cause, but it has happened after attempting to install glfw twice in a row now. The last time I got the error message "could not write bytes broken pipe", however this time I don't get that. I fixed it by reinstalling Ubuntu, but it would be painful to have to do that again.

Comment: did you try `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`?

Comment: Now it skips over the flashing underscore and goes directly to the terminal, but still can't get any gui.

Answer (score 0):

Run run the below commands in the virtual console,

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: if it won't works then try `startx` command.

Comment: sudo service lightdm restart just takes me back to the blinking underscore.
startx gives fatal server error: no screens found.

Comment: run the first command and then restar your pc.